# overflow-y:visible not working when overflow-x:hidden is present

Tags: html, css

Doesn't work properly in Chrome or Firefox. Is there any workaround to this?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
    <h3>overflow-y:visible</h3>

    with overflow-x:hidden
    <div style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:visible;width:100px;height:100px;   position:relative;background:#666;">
        <div style="top:20px;left:20px;    width:420px;height:420px;position:absolute;background:#420;">
        </div>
    </div>

    without overflow-x:hidden
    <div style="overflow-y:visible;width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;background:#666;">
        <div style="top:20px;left:20px; width:420px;height:420px;position:absolute;background:#420;">
        </div>
    </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMNyK/

The real life scenario involves components that absolutely must have overflow-x:hidden, but that will trigger popup-menus that need to be able to break free from the element in y-direction. Should I just position those menus outside their parent components, or is there a better fix?

Comment: I spotted this, which looks like its still an issue in FF (v21) and Chrome (v27). My issue: `overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: hidden;` yet cropping occurs on both axis.

Comment: I ran into this problem today as well, both in FF and Chrome. It certainly looks like a bug rather than expected behavior.

Comment: you getting problem because position:relative;

Comment: No solutions yet? It's been 5 years & 4 months.

Comment: lol It's now almost 2020 and this is still an issue. I found a sort-of workaround by not setting a static height on the element, but it's not a great solution.

Answer (score 58):

This likely has to do with the issue addressed here: [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causes-scroll-bar)

In short, when using `visible` for either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` and something other than `visible` for the other, the `visible` value is interpreted as `auto`.

Comment: is this a bug that browser vendors should fix or spec by W3C? Because it's awful...

Comment: 2.5 years later and this bug still exists

Comment: FF 52 and this still happens. add one more year...

Comment: FF 57, here too

Comment: Guess which issue still exists at the end of 2018... *facepalm*

Comment: This bug is still haunting my projects

Comment: Still a bug.... FF72 can't believe they haven't fixed that one yet!

Comment: 2020 still the same...

Comment: 2021 and this hits harder than covid

Comment: I'm from the future. It's 2045, the issue still exists

Comment: 2022 just knocked in and the issue still exists. :(

Comment: This is legit unacceptable!

Comment: 10 days till 2023 and still: I lost almost a full day trying to figure out why my CSS does not work as expected...

Comment: @BlaM Glad to still be helping, ten years later :)

Comment: The cycle continues....

Comment: September 2023 and we still have this behavior

Comment: I'm from 2024 and we still have it

Answer (score 5):

I think you can get what you want with an extra wrapping `div` that does the hiding but does not have the `position: relative` set ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMNyK/3/)):

```
<div style="overflow-y:visible;width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;background:#666;">
    <div style="overflow-x:hidden">
    ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo  
        <div style="top:20px;left:20px; width:420px;height:420px;position:absolute;background:#420;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work, since the components requiring overflow-y:visible are inside the ones requiring overflow-x:hidden

Comment: @user1185421--First, you said in your question that putting them "outside the parent components" was perhaps the only option. My solution should work as long as those components requiring `overflow-x:hidden` do not have a `position` set on them. This will allow the `absolute` element to relate only to the div that is `overflow-y: visible`.

Comment: @user1185421--[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMNyK/4/) with a wide `div` containing the pop-out div.

Comment: You saved my day, Scotts! Thanks a lot!